# Update caller object directly in javascript prototype function

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to directly update the object calling a javascript prototype function. Consider the code below.

```
var myBool = false;

Boolean.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
  // Works
  myBool = !myBool;

  // Below is how I want it to work. Updating caller instead
  //this = !this;
};

$("#btnReverse").click(function() {
  myBool.reverse();
});
```

Is this possible? I know I could solve it differently, but I would like to keep my code as clean as possible, and not send any parameters to the reverse function.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you are not allowed to assign values to "this". So what I am looking for then, should be a way to identify what object invoked the function, so I can update that object.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Boolean.prototype.reverse = function reverse() {
  return !this;
};
```

Comment: Seems that does not update the variable.
Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7r3asvcu/4/